# Blackberry convert Base64 data to byte array showing IOException

Tags: blackberry

I have developed the below code to convert base64 string data to byte array but it's showing `IOException`

```java
public static EncodedImage getProfileByteArray(String profilePic){
    byte[] data=profilePic.getBytes();
    byte[] base64Data;
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    EncodedImage fullImage=null;
    try {
        base64Data = Base64InputStream.decode(data, 0, data.length);
        fullImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(base64Data, 0, base64Data.length);
        bitmap = fullImage.getBitmap();
        System.out.println(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e+"lkllllllllllllllll");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e+"lkllllllllllllllll");
    }
    return fullImage;
}
```

The way is that i am calling a webservice through which i am getting base64 image string and trying to convert this base64 string to byte array to display image in `EncodedImage` format.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? Does the exception have a message?

Comment: Hi this line is showing IOException and there is no message with exception base64Data = Base64InputStream.decode(data, 0, data.length);

Comment: It throws IOException in case of decoding error. Did you try to validate your Base64 data for example here http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/

Comment: Make sure that your `data` array is not empty.

Comment: Hi Rafael I have done it,the problem was the wrong base64 data format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display an image from the url fetched from the webservice? The url is the image returned from the webservice? If that is so, please try the below code and let me know:

```
public Bitmap connectServerForImage(String url) {

          HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
          DataOutputStream httpDataOutput = null;
          InputStream httpInput = null;
          int rc;

          Bitmap bitmp = null;
          try {
           httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+ ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=S TCP");
            rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
           if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
           }
           httpInput = httpConnection.openInputStream();
           InputStream inp = httpInput;
           byte[] b = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inp);
           EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
           return hai.getBitmap();

          } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("URL Bitmap Error........" + ex.getMessage());
          } finally {
           try {
            if (httpInput != null)
             httpInput.close();
            if (httpDataOutput != null)
             httpDataOutput.close();
            if (httpConnection != null)
             httpConnection.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

           }
          }
          return bitmp;
         }
```

Comment: No Sarah i have done that successfully.I need to display an image from base64 string data.